# Android, log sensor data to xml file

Tags: android, xml, logging, sensors

I am trying to read sensors data and log it into xml file while recording a video, any idea how to read the data and write it into xml file

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to create a buffer since you will get many data in small periods. You can create a background task (timers, threads, handlers or service) to keep tracking your sensor and write the data in a buffer while another thread can write from buffer to a xml file or shared prefs.